# How to show that Faradays law is compatible with conservation of energy mathematically

Tags: electromagnetism

Faradays law states that

$$
\int_{\partial \Sigma} \vec{E} \,\mathrm{d} \vec{s} = -\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} t} \int_{\Sigma} \vec{B} \, \mathrm{d} \vec{A}
$$

The minus sign occurs if we connect the orientations of $\mathrm{d} \vec{A}$ and $\mathrm{d} \vec{s}$ via a right hand rule (if we use a left hand rule it would be gone).

How to show mathematically and generally (i.e. not restricted to an example) that (provided the right hand orientation convention) if the minus sign wasn't there, energy conservation would be violated and that if the minus is there, that it is compatible with conservation of energy.

Comment: I don't believe that energy conservation would be violated without the negative sign. I believe it boils down to conventions.

Comment: @SeñorO: As I said assuming the right handed orientation convention, then it should be violated...

Comment: Not just right hand convention but positive/negative convention and north/south convention. Energy = $|\vec{E}|^2 + |\vec{B}|^2$

Comment: If you flip the sign in Lenz's rule or, equivalently the curl B Maxwell equation, you do get a violation of energy conservation, as I show below.

Answer (score 2):

Taking advantage of the vector analytical identity $\textrm{div}(\textbf{U}\times \textbf{V}) = \textbf{V} \cdot \textrm{curl}\textbf{U}-\textbf{U} \cdot \textrm{curl}\textbf{V}$ you can derive from the first two Maxwell's equations that $$\textrm{div}(\textbf{E}\times \textbf{H}) = \textbf{E} \cdot \textbf{J} + \textbf{H} \cdot \dot {\textbf{B}}+\textbf{E} \cdot \dot {\textbf{D}} \tag1$$
Here $\textbf{S}=\textbf{E}\times \textbf{H}$ is the Poynting vector representing the radiated EM power per unit area, $\textbf{E} \cdot \textbf{J}$ is the Joule dissipation, the terms $\textbf{H} \cdot \dot {\textbf{B}}$ and $\textbf{E} \cdot \dot {\textbf{D}}$ represent the time rates of magnetic and the electric energies per unit volume. Thus Equation 1 (Poynting's theorem) is the energy conservation of electromagnetics. You would not get it unless you include Lenz's law that is the proper negative sign in the 2nd Maxwell equation.

Comment: This is a really good answer, but I don't think it quite aligns with the level of EM knowledge asked in the question. I think further clarification  for OP would be helpful

Answer (score 1):

The induced electromotive force (emf) must give rise to a current whose magnetic field opposes the change in original magnetic flux.  I.e., Lenz's law.  I always thought of this as a magnetic form of Newton's third law.   Since it takes energy to increase the current in a wire, you're transferring power from the magnetic field surrounding the circuit.  So, neglecting resistive loss in wire, 
$$ \int _ {\partial \Sigma} {\vec E} \,  d{\vec s} + \frac{d}{dt} \int _{\Sigma} 
{\vec B} \cdot d{\vec A} = 0$$ is a statement of conservation of energy.

**Added based on @freecharly's questions:**  You don't need Lenz's law if you have Maxwell's $\nabla \times B = - \frac{\partial E}{\partial t}$.  In a nutshell, pick a surface with a boundary, apply Stokes theorem and out pops the equation above.  But that's a formal argument. The conceptual point is, as Feynman says, a current in self-induction has "inertia" because the inductive effects try to keep the flow of charge constant. **Suppose the minus sign were flipped.** Then induced current would actually add to existing current in the loop. This in turn would increase the magnetic flux and on and on. This would violate energy conservation.

Comment: How does this relate to the question regarding the  conservation of energy?

Comment: Lenz's law is a consequence of conservation of energy applied to electromagnetic induction.   Standard stuff.  I tried to come up with an conceptual answer after reading  @Señor O's comment above.  Feel free to improve.

Comment: But the question is about Faraday's law which only gives an induced voltage (EMF) and  doesn't need a wire with a current flowing as is  the case in Lenz's law. Thus I wonder how the sign of Faraday's law relates to energy conservation without invoking Lenz.

Comment: For a formal answer, the minus sign comes from the Maxwell Curl B equation.  Just pick a surface with a boundary, apply Stokes theorem and voila, Lenz's law for free.   The conceptual point is that, as Feynman says, a current in self-induction has "inertia" because the inductive effects try to keep the flow of charge constant.   Suppose the minus sign were flipped.  Then  induced  current would actually reinforce existing current.  This in turn would increase the magnetic flux and so on.  This violates energy conservation.

Comment: @freecharly I have extended my answer based on your feedback.  Thanks.

Comment: John, I understand your argument based on the current flow. However, the Faraday-Maxwell  law itself doesn't need a current to flow. The electric field induced by the time-changing magnetic field also exists in vacuum. One might try to look at the energy necessary to build up this electric field and look at the energy conservation.

Comment: Isn't this @hyportnex's answer?   I was trying to be more conceptual.  Thanks.

Comment: John, @hyportnex  just stated the Poynting theorem of which he claims that it would not follow if the sign in the Faraday-Maxwell's equation would be changed. But he would have to show that in the derivation of the Poynting theorem with the changed sign. In the end your argument with Lenz's law is correct because even if you were only in vacuum you can always argue that the movement of a test charge in the induced field would lead to a contradictory result.

Answer (score 0):

I'll address just this statement: "The minus sign occurs if we connect the orientations of $\mathrm{d} \vec{A}$ and $\mathrm{d} \vec{s}$ via a right hand rule (if we use a left hand rule it would be gone)."

This is, I believe, misleading. If we change hand rules for the connection between $\mathrm{d} \vec{A}$ and $\mathrm{d} \vec{s}$ in Faraday's law, we must also, for consistency, do so when relating a magnetic field to the current producing it. The result is that the minus sign must still be present in Faraday's law even if we change sign convention.

To give an example, suppose we have a loop in the plane of the screen. Let a clockwise circulation around the loop be positive and the direction out of the screen be positive (a left hand rule). According to the Faraday-Lenz law an external magnetic field increasing in the positive direction will produce a negative emf and a negative current in the loop. But this current, again applying the left hand rule, will produce a field into the screen, that is a negative magnetic field through the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Faraday's law is the integral form of $\nabla \times \vec{E} = -\frac{\partial \vec{B}}{\partial t}$ , which is one of Maxwell's equations.

Maxwell's equations are the Euler-Lagrange equations for the Lagrangian $\cal{L} = \frac{1}{4}\epsilon_0 F_{\mu\nu} F^{\mu\nu}$.

Noether's theorem says that any space-time translation invariant lagrangian $\cal{L}$ implies a conserved energy-momentum density, $\partial_\mu T^{\mu\nu}=0$.

In this case $T^{\mu\nu}=\epsilon_0 F^\mu_\rho F^{\nu\rho}-g^{\mu\nu}\cal{L}$ is conserved.
Now the energy is $T^{00}=\frac{1}{2}\epsilon_0 (E^2+B^2)$ and the energy transport density is $T^{0i}=(\vec{E}\times\vec{B})^i$.

So $\frac{1}{2}\epsilon_0 \partial_t (E^2+B^2) = \epsilon_0\vec{\nabla}\cdot(\vec{E}\times\vec{B})$.

Note that this only applies where charge and current vanish.